# Getting ID of Parent Object in Route

Tags: ember.js, routes, ember-data

I have an Ember 1.11 app created with ember-cli 0.2.3. I have the following in my router.js file:

```
this.route('ownedGames', function() {
    this.route('gamePlays', {path: ":owned_game_id/plays"}, function() { });
});
```

This allows me to use the following URL:

```
http://localhost:4200/ownedGames/1/plays
```

When I visit that URL, I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed '<ember-bgg@model:owned-game::ember470:1>' (wrapped in (generated ownedGames.gamePlays controller))
```

Here is my route for GamePlay

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        console.log("Getting game plays from store");
        return this.store.find('gamePlay', {ownedGame: params.owned_game_id});
    }
});
```

And this is how I've modeled my fixture data:

```
OwnedGame.reopenClass({
    FIXTURES: [
        { id: "1", rating: "8.25", game: "1", plays: [1,2]},
        { id: "2", rating: "8.25", game: "2", plays: []},
        { id: "3", rating: "8.25", game: "3", plays: []},
        { id: "4", rating: "8.25", game: "4", plays: []}
    ]
});

GamePlay.reopenClass({
    FIXTURES: [
        {id: "1", date: "2015-01-01", ownedGame: "1"},
        {id: "2", date: "2015-02-01", ownedGame: "1"}
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your router map you set `:owned_game_dd` to be available in the `ownedGames.ownedGame` route, so the parameter is not going to be available in `ownedGames.ownedGame.gamePlays` route as you would think. In order to get the parameters form another route you have to get them from the [`transition`](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/bfcc15ee3ac2b2b3e4dad6aa0d7a447936302f5a/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/route.js#L1327) object available as a second parameter to the `model` method.

```
App.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('ownedGames', function() {
     this.route('ownedGame', {path: '/:owned_game_id'}, function() {
       this.route('gamePlays', {path: '/plays'}, function() { });
   });
  });
});

App.OwnedGamesOwnedGameGamePlaysRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params, transition) {
         var id = transition.params['ownedGames.ownedGame'].owned_game_id;

         return this.store.find('gamePlay', id);
    }
});
```

**http://emberjs.jsbin.com/favucawadi/1/edit?html,js,output**

Comment: @Gregg you should have it available https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/bfcc15ee3ac2b2b3e4dad6aa0d7a447936302f5a/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/route.js#L1327. if you can set up a jsbin we can debug furthur

Comment: Thanks. I've made enough changes, I'm not sure how valid this question is anymore. I'll see if I can edit it to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

If your ownedGame route is setting its model, you can grab the model reference via [modelFor()](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_modelFor) and pluck off its id.  This will abstract you away from what your actual param name is for the parent route as well.

Ember has no docs on what's private and public on the transition instance, but the fact that they pass in params AND the transition to the model hook suggests to me that it's not 100% safe to grab params out of the transition object unless you're cool with non-deprecation-notice-breaking-changes months down the road.

Also, this.resource() is being deprecated in 1.13; if this is a new project I'd opt for this.route() all the way.

Comment: Do you have a link regarding the deprecation of resource?

Comment: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/router-this-resource-gone-from-documentation-v1-11-0/7833/2